# What does 'Value<T>' stand for in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I met some code like

```js
type Value = {
  [name: string]: string;
};

function foo(a: Value) {
  console.log(a);
}

foo({ name: "foo" });  //ok
foo("hello world");    //error
```

It's easy to see that `Value` means an object.

Then I met this:

```js
type Value<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};

function a<T>(a: Value<T>): void {
  console.log(a);
}

a({ name: "ff" });  //ok
a(1);               //ok
```

So, what does `Value<T>` mean? Seems quite like a simple `<T>`, but I don't understand the particular situation to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, `T` is a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). It might be helpful to think of it kind of like a variable in JavaScript, but it's for a type instead of a runtime value.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOwDwDkCGBbaEAHsBKgCaJSLDwCWqA5gHxQC8UA3gLABQUUqPBABcUHPgDcvAL5SevAGYBXVAGNgtNFFXwI2EnCRb0AFShES5StTqMmACkH5RJgJSjDKDCZbc+UXWAleFROASEoWRleXlU0agFaVQBrNm1dfQhPNHsAckwkgAtkABtsRFzXCSgAehqoYELoUEgoZAVElKhaRA8EL3QAIgLVYrLEQaZeIA)

```ts
type Person<Name extends string> = {
  name: Name;
};

function createPerson <T extends string>(name: T): Person<T> {
  return { name };
}

const nick = createPerson('Nicholas'); // the type of nick is: Person<"Nicholas">
```